# wmic MEMORYCHIP get Speed command not working in window 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, memory, operating-systems

Getting message `No Instance(s) Available.` when enter the command `wmic MEMORYCHIP get Speed` in Windows 10.
I want to check Ram speed in Computer.

Comment: Works fine here. Have you uninstalled .Net?

Comment: Have you tried it from a CMD window started "Run as Administrator"? Usually this error is either syntax (extra space, bad spelling etc.) or rights.

Comment: @Debra yes I tried. Still got same response.

Comment: @harrymc can you give me link. I will check in my pc if not, I will install.